Improving Semantic Search Performance with NLP AI Model in Large Database
I need your help to improve the speed of semantic search in my Django web application. My app is designed to allow users to search a database of videos to find out which video discusses a particular topic and at what time code.
To achieve this, I have generated SRT (subtitle) files for each video and stored them in a database. I then use an NLP (Natural Language Processing) model to link the user's search query to the stored data. Currently, I am using the BERT model (https://huggingface.co/Sakil/sentence_similarity_semantic_search) that I found on Hugging Face.
However, the search process takes a long time when the database is large.
Here is my current code for the search:
def search_results(request):
    results = []
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        query = request.GET['query']

        # Retrieve data from the database
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT time_code, texte FROM Searchapp_soustitres")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()

        # Transform the data into a format similar to your document
        document = [(time_code, texte) for time_code, texte in rows]

        # Load the pre-trained NLP model
        model = SentenceTransformer('SeyedAli/Multilingual-Text-Semantic-Search-Siamese-BERT-V1')

        # Encode the user's query and the documents in the database using the NLP model
        query_emb = model.encode(query)
        doc_embs = [model.encode(sentence) for timecode, sentence in document]

        # Calculate the cosine similarity between the user's query and each document in the database
        scores = [util.cos_sim(query_emb, doc_emb) for doc_emb in doc_embs]

        # Sort the scores in descending order and get the indices of the top three scores
        top_three_indices = sorted(range(len(scores)), key=lambda i: scores[i], reverse=True)[:3]

        # Get the top three results with their time codes and similarity scores
        results = [(document[i][1], document[i][0], scores[i]) for i in top_three_indices]

        print(query)
        print(results)

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'results': results})

My question is: am I on the right track or am I making things more complicated than they need to be? Is there a better way to improve the speed of semantic search? For example, a more performant AI model or a different approach to storing and searching the data?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!
